# How to change flask location to work in more than one local path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip, pyenv

I am using VScode
I installed flask in the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11` as shown trough `pip show flask`.
My problem is it is only working in the local path `usr/local/bin/python3`. When I switch to a different path or my virtual enviroment `~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/bin/python`. As soon as I try to install flask with `pip install flask` or `pip3 install flask` I get the error message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->flask) (2.1.2)
```

I also want it to be working in my codespace, but there it is the same problem, furthermore I dont have my local path with the installed flask, so I always get the message as soon as I try to install it there:

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.6.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.3.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (2.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.1.2 in /home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.1.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.1.3 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from flask) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->flask) (2.1.2)
```

Is there any way to change the location from flask to work everywhere or at least isntall it somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried `~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/bin/python -m pip install flask`?

Comment: it seems like it worked. I have not thought about typing in the path and then wiring the command with -m, thanks!